# jsonData will not Print on console there is no erros it just will not print

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, cordova, ionic-framework

```
.controller('StocksCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams','$http',
  function($scope, $stateParams) {

    //http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/YHOO/quote?bypass=true&format=json&view=detail
    $http.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/YHOO/quote?bypass=true&format=json&view=detail")
      .then(function(jsonData) {
        console.log(jsonData);
      });



  $scope.ticker = $stateParams.stockTicker;
}]);
```

Comment: does my answer help you??. If not try to replicate the issue on  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) and that will help us debug.

Comment: __OR__ he is missing console plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

you missed to inject `$http` in the function.

```
.controller('StocksCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http',
    function($scope, $stateParams,$http) {

        //http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/YHOO/quote?bypass=true&format=json&view=detail
        $http.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/YHOO/quote?bypass=true&format=json&view=detail")
            .then(function(jsonData) {
                console.log(jsonData);
            });

        $scope.ticker = $stateParams.stockTicker;
    }
]);
```